# Google OAuth 2.0 Response

Tags: oauth-2.0

I need help figuring out why my OAuth 2.0 response is always something like:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=[BUNCH OF LETTERS AND NUMBERS]&xsrfsign=[BUNCH OF LETTERS AND NUMBERS]

This is the response after I login to my Google account and click allow access to the application.

It's nothing like the response I'm expecting according to the documentation (http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer.html#handlingtheresponse)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you did not specified the language you are coding.

Secondly, make sure you specify the corect RedirectUri. You can get or set if from google console (https://code.google.com/apis/console/).

Then, for this kind of url https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/approval?as=.....&xsrfsign=..... you won't get the authorization code from the url but from the content of the page:
[image]

I have extracted it from the raw code of the page: [C# code]

```
string []s=webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.InnerHtml.Split (new string [] {"value=\"", "\""}, StringSplitOptions.None);
string authCode=s[165];
```